# facebook ads api click tracking tag

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I want to use facebook's click tracking tag support in the ads api for external website ads. Here is related documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/click-tags/

What is the expected behavior when the user clicks on an ad with a tracking tag?

1. The user is re-directed to the page url specified in the creative, facebook fires the click tracking tag in the background.

OR

1. The user is re-directed to the landing page configured in the click tracking tag, facebook ignores the page url in the creative

Answer (score 2):

Like view tags, click tags do not affect the URL you specify in the ad and the user isn't redirect to the click tag url.

The click tracking tag is just a 1x1 pixel that is loaded when the user clicks on the ad, allowing view tag vendors such as Atlas and DoubleClick to provide some attribution modeling.